# Visual Studio Code Python code navigation on SSH

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have setup a remote location code in Visual Studio Code with the information provided on https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh

I added the Remote Development extension for the same.

Now I am able to access the code which is on remote location but I am not able to navigate through the code -> go to function definition from function call. Generally Ctlr + Click works for the code which is on the Laptop, but it is not working for Remote Code.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Did you install the Python extension after connecting to the remote machine?

Comment: @BrettCannon, Oh, Thanks a lot. It worked. I had Python extension installed on my machine, but missed on installing it on Remote machine.

Comment: @GarimaAgarwal do you just install the extension in the visual code in the remote machine?

Comment: @konstantin, Yes. You need to install it on the remote machine.